# To take an image and place as profile picture in tab

Tags: android, camera, gallery

I am trying to change the profile picture inside tab : To change the picture I have two options either use camera or take the image from gallery.

Can someone please guide me ?

If I use the camera option I will need to take an image and store it in a folder in SD card and then the picture should be changed.

Comment: What have you tried? we can help solving your problems,but cannot write complete code for you...

Comment: "inside tab" What tab?  Is that the name of some piece of software?  A tab *inside* a piece of software?  Or the soft drink?  Additionally, is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

This how you can take get image from camera, put this code in your activity class:

```
private final static int CAMERA_RESULT = 0;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT)
    {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

    }
}

private void startCamera(final Activity theActivity)
{
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    theActivity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_RESULT);

}
```

And don`t forget to add this code to your manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
```